# How to get value from a java map using key in a jsp, but key is a javascript value

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a jsp page , In this page I get a hash map from request attribute and I want to extract value for a specific key . The key is availble on jsp . how can I extarct value  from map using this key?

I solved this problem by converting java map to java script associative array and then I could fetch value from that array. I would like to share the code :

```
<%
Map<String,String> currencyCodeMap = (Map<String,String>)application.getAttribute("currPrecisionCodeMap"); 
%>

<script language="javascript">


        var map = new Array();
        <%
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : currencyCodeMap.entrySet()) {%>
                map['<%=entry.getKey()%>'] = '<%=entry.getValue()%>';
        <%}
        %>

var currencyCode = document.AccForm.currencyname.options[document.AccForm.currencyname.selectedIndex].text;

   alert(map[currencyCode ]);// gives value

</script>
```

above code is working fine but Can Someone provide better solution??

Comment: Why can't you just access the property from "currencyCodeMap" on the JSP side?  It's really messy to mix JSP and JavaScript for a purpose like this; JSP is perfectly capable of extracting values from Map instances.

Comment: I hope you are aware of this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: as you are already using scriptlet, then why dont you iterate the map and fetch the required value in scriptlet itself.

Comment: @Pointy: Can you please provide some code how jsp is capable of extracting values from map.You can use my example

Comment: @Nitesh Mishra : I had mentioned that I get key from a java script variable.

Comment: Well it depends on exactly where the key is coming from, but map access in JSP is via the `[ ]` operator. Like, `currencyCodeMap[ key ]`

Comment: as you are getting the key from form element, then you may submit the form with same page in the action, and then you can retrieve the key using `request` in scriptlet. Secondly, you may use AJAX and pass the key to another JSP and get back the value. As, merging JAVA and JavaScript is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, you have init your hashmap in JSP using , than using JSTL u can iterate it.

```
<jsp:useBean id="hm" type="java.util.Hashtable<java.lang.Long, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>" scope="request"/>

<c:forEach items="${hm[key]}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.value}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Also, you can do next:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("key", your_key);
```

And than using it in JSTL:

```
${your_key}
```